# joining three tables each with an incomplete set of each others' keys

Tags: t-sql

I have three tables (actually temp tables, each the result of other queries), with very similar data sets; I need to "condense", for lack of a better term, and my limited SQL knowledge is stopping me.

For example, we have Budgets by Code, Estimates by Code, and Actuals by Code.  Not all possible values for Code exist in any of the three, nor even in another accessible table.

```
Budgets
1  $13
2  $22
4  $44
7  $71

Estimates
1  $14
4  $49
5  $55

Actuals
2  $21
3  $33
5  $57
7  $70
```

What I want:

```
Code   Bgt   Est   Act
 1      13    14     0
 2      22     0    21
 3       0     0    33
 4      44    49     0
 5       0    55    57
 7      71     0    70
```

(I don't have to have 0 when there's no value, that's just for illustrative purposes.)

I just have no idea how to approach this - any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Try using Full Outer Join, In your case query will look like -

Select ISNULL(Bgt.Code,ISNULL(EST.Code,Act.Code)) AS Code, 
   ISNULL(Bgt.Budget,0) AS Bgt,
   ISNULL(Est.Estimate,0) AS Est,
   ISNULL(Act.Actual,0) AS Bgt   
FROM Budget Bgt   
FULL OUTER JOIN Estimates Est ON Est.Code=Bgt.Code
FULL OUTER JOIN Actuals Act  ON Act.Code=bgt.Code
```

Comment: Thanks!  That ISNULL function was new to me, and exactly what I needed!